# Substring Index mysql

Tags: mysql, substring

I need some help with Substring index function in mysql.I need to return a part of the following string from a starting pattern to the end of the string:

```
 Michael Jackson Jannet  ->  SubString 1: Michael   / SubString 2: Jackson Jannet
 Lincoln Obama Kennedy Washington  ->  SubString 1: Lincoln / SubString 2: Obama Kennedy Washington
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the InStr() function fit your needs?
Search for the first white space in your string, you know the position now. Then cut the string in two substrings using Left() and Mid():

```
pos = InStr("Michael Jackson Janet"," ")
substring1 = Left("Michael Jackson Janet", pos - 1)
substring2 = Mid("Michael Jackson Janet", pos)
```

If you insist on using the SubString() function, you can do it like this:

```
pos = InStr("Michael Jackson Janet"," ")
substring1 = SubString("Michael Jackson Janet", 1, pos - 1)
substring2 = SubString("Michael Jackson Janet", pos + 1)
```

Does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring('Michael Jackson Jannet',1,(locate (' ','Michael Jackson Jannet'))) as firstNBame,
      substring('Michael Jackson Jannet',(locate (' ','Michael Jackson Jannet'))) as secondName;
```

Comment: have you got an explanation to go with the code? Might not be obvious to everyone what exactly is going on.